# How does void(**rptr)() and the call in main() work in this solution to printing 1-100 with no loops in C++?

Tags: c++

In this Quora answer i stumbled upon this piece of code and would like to understand whats happening: [How can I print 1 to 100 in C++ without a loop, goto or recursion?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-print-1-to-100-in-C++-without-a-loop-goto-or-recursion/answer/Mark-Gordon-6)

I asked my programming teacher and he said he's not too familiar with `alloca()`, but he was sure this program had undefined behavior, and that i'd better ask on SO.
Worth to note that the OP of the answer on Quora gave no guarantee this would work on someone else's system.

I have trouble understanding what `void(**rptr)()` does and how the call in `main()` works, why `* 200`?.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int num;
void(**rptr)();
void foo() {
  if(num >= 100) exit(0);
  std::cout << ++num << std::endl;
  *rptr++ = foo;
}
int main() {
  rptr = (void(**)())alloca(sizeof(*rptr) * 200) - 1;
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That use trick on how asm is generated...

Comment: fwiw, in one way or the other you need a loop to print numbers from 1 to 100. This is just a game on what you actually call a "loop". The code does a great deal at obfuscating the "loop" with stuff that surely is non-portable and relies on UB

Comment: @idclev463035818 i'd label it as obfuscating recursion, rather than a loop. The intention is that `foo` ends with a call to `foo`.

Comment: "why `* 200`" probably only because 200 > 100. I assume 101 would "work" just as well, and 0 has an outside chance.

Comment: @idclev463035818: `std::cout << "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";` prints number 1-10 without loop (unless you consider that printing string is a loop, then I still might write char by char ;) )

Comment: @Jarod42 imho this is an esotheric exercise, so I allow myself to apply an esotheric definition of "loop". Yes this is a loop in the widest sense because you could not tell the different between yours and `for (int i=1;i<11;++i) std::cout << i << " ";`. Maybe a compiler turns your example into a loop, you wouldn't notice

Comment: @idclev463035818: extra space in your version ;-) But we agree that printing numbers from 1 to N requires some kind of loop.

Comment: For anyone interested, this guy went to the actual length of making sure no loops occur at any stage through a microcontroller, crazy stuff: https://github.com/topin89/loopless_hundred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a horrible hack which leverages undefined behavoir. Analysing undefined behavoir is pretty pointless, but sometimes its interesting to dig in and find out exactly why.

Basically, what is happening is the `alloca(...)` is allocating enough memory to store 200 function pointers *on the stack*. So far, unusual but nothing bad. But the key is the -1 at the end - its returning memory which is one *before* this store. So `rptr` is pointing to the stack into an unknown location.

Then `foo` is called. At the end of `foo` we write the address of `foo` to `rptr`. But `rptr` is one *before* the valid memory so we're overwriting something else.

What that something else happens to be is the return address for where `foo` returns to (which should be `main`). So instead of returning to `main`, it basically "returns" to the start of `foo`. And this repeats until we get to the exit.

Its basically moderately controlled stack smashing. And will only work on architectures with calling conventions where the return address is put onto the stack in this manor.